# Is there a slick way to get to the "residual" of a set difference?

Tags: python, set

I got this problem:

Given an Iterable `i`, two disjoint sets `a` and `b` (where usually `a` and `b` each contain far more elements than `i`) remove all the elements from `a` that are found in `i` and add all the elements of `i` not shared by `a` to `b`.

For example:

```
i = [0, 3]
a = {1, 2, 3, 4}
b = {5, 6, 7, 8}
```

should result in

```
a = {1, 2, 4}
b = {0, 5, 6, 7, 8}
```

[image: Venn diagram of the example]

In terms of this diagram, the grey subsets are supposed to be empty. After the operation, I want the light blue subsets to be joined to `b` and the yellow overlap to be removed from `a`.

To solve it I wrote this Python function:

```
def foo(i, a, b):
    set_i = set(i)
    b |= set_i - a
    a -= set_i
```

This works but it is not very pretty and still does things (the difference of `a` and `set_i`) twice.

What would be a more efficient way?

Comment: I don't see the difference being computed twice: `i - a` is no easy complement of `a - i`.

Comment: Sorry, I dont think I understood that "no easy complement" part. How is the difference not computed in both those lines?

Comment: I suggest you make a Venn diagram, 3 circles with all overlaps and outline your desired results. I assume, that all elements of b shall be kept, even if they are in the intersection of b and a.

Comment: This made me realize I forgot to specify that a and b are expected to be disjoint.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do it straightforward as you described it:

```py
def foo(i, a, b):

    for el in i:
        if el in a:
            a.remove(el)
        else:
            b.add(el)
```

I wouldn't mutate a and b in place, especially since they are provided as arguments to a function, a safe version would be

```py
def foo(i, a, b):

    a_new = a.copy()
    b_new = b.copy()

    for el in i:
        if el in a:
            a_new.remove(el)
        else:
            b_new.add(el)

    return a_new, b_new
```

It will be more efficient in the general case since `i` being an iterable (which could be an actual iterator), you only iterate over it once. If you convert it to a set, internally it will be iterated over once, and then again at least two times for each set operation.

You could also use `groupby` from `itertools` like this:

```py
from itertools import groupby

def foo(i, a, b):

    for in_a, i_group in groupby(i, key=lambda x: x in a):
    
        if in_a:
            a -= set(i_group)
        else:
            b |= set(i_group)
```

Comment: Could do it like that but I assumed that iterating i only once does not make up for the extra work of removing from a and adding to b in single steps as opposed to doing it by set operations.

I also admit it is not great style to mutate the input args, but it is what I wanted to do with this and copying their contents on every call is not gonna cut it.

groupby is close to what I imagine but it looks to me like calling this lambda is just extra work and also the function requires the input iterator to be sorted on the key.

Comment: Adding to a and removing from b looks like extra work, but internally the set operations work item by item anyway, so only your code looks less inefficient, but the actual time to perform it is faster, you can time it and see what's more efficient.

Comment: Agreed, seems like they work the same. However now I am not sure if the explicit check for "el in a" is extra work since there might be something like it inside set.remove already. So maybe this cannot be done with absolute efficiency in python.

Comment: @TheodorStraube I just noticed though that my first solution has a bug - if the same element appears multiple times in `i` and also in `a`, its first occurrence will be removed from `a`, but the subsequent ones will be added to `b`, since it will no longer be present in `a`. The last solution using `groupby` works correctly, since the groups generation is performed before the groups are iterated over.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
def foo(i, a, b):
    a -= set(i)
    b |= a
```

Comment: That is not at all equivalent

Comment: That works for moving the elements of i to a and b but also moves everything that was previously in a into b.

Comment: Can you give us some example of what can be the input and the expected output please